# Accessing itunesConnect API for App Download/Installation information using nodejs

Tags: node.js, app-store-connect

I am using the nodejs implementation https://www.npmjs.com/package/itunesconnect
to access itunes-connect API for my App. 
What I need is data pertaining to the App-download/Install.
Basically I want to know how many downloads happened for each month.
I am not sure how to get this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken and modified from [registry:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/itunesconnect)

**Basic example**

This example shows how to fetch ranked report data from last 30 days and timed report from last 4 weeks with a week interval.

**Query**:

```
var itc = require("itunesconnect");
var Report = itc.Report;

// Connect to iTunes 
var itunes = new itc.Connect('apple@id.com', 'password');

// Simple ranked report 
itunes.request(Report.ranked().time(30, 'days'), function(error, result) {
    console.log(result);
});

// Or 
itunes.request(Report('timed').time(4, 'weeks').interval('week'), function(error, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

**The Result:**

```
[
  {
    "key": 0,
    "title": "App Name ",
    "rptgDesc": "App",
    "contentSpecificTypeId": 1,
    "contentSpecificTypeName": "iOS App",
    "contentGrpCd": "Apps",
    "contentProviderId": 0,
    "artistName": "Artist Name",
    "contentProviderName": "Provider Name",
    "units": 7684
  },
  {
    "key": 0,
    "title": "In App Name ...",
    "rptgDesc": "In App",
    "contentSpecificTypeId": 3,
    "contentSpecificTypeName": "Auto-Renewable Subscription",
    "contentGrpCd": "Apps",
    "contentProviderId": 0,
    "contentProviderName": "Provider Name",
    "units": 2886
  }



]
```

Now you can access the amount of downloads through the `units` key in the returned json.

Hope that helps, Julian.

Comment: I am trying to use "npm install autoingestion".  But I get this error:  message: 'Please enter all the required parameters. For help, please download the latest User Guide from the Sales and Trends module in iTunes Connect.',
  name: 'Invalid Parameters Error' or 
I tried "npm install apple-autoingestion" as well. But there is no option to specify user name and password here. Any suggestions??