# connect to itunes via nodejs or reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, app-store-connect

I want to connect my existing web app to itunes but could able to find anything on google... I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801449/accessing-itunesconnect-api-for-app-download-installation-information-using-node) but didn't work for me can anyone please help what  I am doing wrong here or can anyone suggest me any other way to connect it to itunes.

```
var itc = require("itunesconnect");
var Report = itc.Report;

// Connect to iTunes 
var itunes = new itc.Connect('apple@id.com', 'password');

// Simple ranked report 
itunes.request(Report.ranked().time(30, 'days'), function(error, result) {
    console.log(result);
});

// Or 
itunes.request(Report('timed').time(4, 'weeks').interval('week'), function(error, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Edit--> console for itnues

```
Connect {
  options:
   { baseURL: 'https://itunesconnec
     apiURL: 'https://reportingitc2
     loginURL: 'https://idmsa.apple
     appleWidgetKey: '22d448248055b
     concurrentRequests: 2,
     errorCallback: [Function: erro
     loginCallback: [Function: logi
  _cookies: [],
  _queue:
   { tasks: [],
     concurrency: 2,
     saturated: null,
     empty: null,
     drain: null,
     started: false,
     paused: true,
     push: [Function: push],
     kill: [Function: kill],
     unshift: [Function: unshift],
     process: [Function: process],
     length: [Function: length],
     running: [Function: running],
     idle: [Function: idle],
     pause: [Function: pause],
     resume: [Function: resume] }
 }
```

Comment: do you see any errors ?

Comment: thanks for the reply @GeorgeBailey... No I don't get anything either in error parameter or in result parameter...

Comment: @VishalSolanki Anything in console? What's in the `itunes` object after Connect ?

Comment: @Frederik.L updated the question... ***Anything in console*** no nothing in console for `result`